# Nock is not intercepting request if it runs multiples test in certain order

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai, nock

I'm creating some unit test for my endpoint. This endpoint will fetch data from an external API and send diff responses depending  on finding a certain item on that data fetched or if there is an error fetching data from that external API.

I have 2 unit test, one makes a call to the external API and the other I mock it with nock to intercept that external API call and send back an error. The problem: When I run both inside describe, the one which I used nock fails. If I run both test separated, they both succeed. If I reorder the unit test, putting the one with the nock first and the other second, they both pass. I read and tried some solutions related to nock and didn't work.

here is the unit test:

```
 describe("x endpoint testing", () => {
    afterEach("Restore Nocks", async (done) => {
        if (nock.isActive()) {
            nock.cleanAll();
            nock.restore();
        }
        done();
    });

    it("should return 200", (done) => {
        chai
            .request(server)
            .get(`/endpoint/${realParams}`)
            .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .send()
            .then((res) => {
                res.should.have.status(200);
                done();
            })
            .catch(done);
    });

    it("should return 400 if a connection error occur with API", (done) => {
        if (!nock.isActive()) nock.activate();

        const apiNock = nock(process.env.API_ENDPOINT)
            .log(console.log)
            .get(`/api`)
            .replyWithError({
                message: "Something awful happened",
                code: "404",
            });

        chai
            .request(server)
            .get(`/endpoint/${fakeParams}`)
            .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .send()
            .then((res) => {
                expect(apiNock.isDone()).to.be.true;
                res.should.have.status(400);
                res.body.should.have.property("error");
                done();
            })
            .catch(done);
    });
});
```

Comment: I haven't tried to run your code, but I assume the issue is with the activating and restoring Nock. That's not something you should have to do. Nock with auto-activate on import and, unless told otherwise, wont interfere with tests that don't use it. All you need in the afterEach is `nock.cleanAll();`. remove the rest

Comment: also is this Mocha or Jest? You're afterEach uses a `done` callback and `async`. For Mocha that's not good, one or the other. I'm not sure if Jest is the same.

Comment: @MattR.Wilson, waht do you mean by nock with auto-activate on import? do I need to add something else on import to 'activate' that auto-activate or does it already set to on? If its already on, I tried to keep only the nock.clenAll() and got the same results.
I'm using Mocha. The afterEach with both was a mistake, it should have been only done.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It should read "Nock will* auto-activate on import"

Comment: Oh I see, but even when I removed ```nock.restore()``` the problem persist

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to outline exactly what the issues are in your example, however, I think issues lay outside the provided code. Instead, here is some code that runs and passes no matter which order the tests are run.

My hope is that you can compare this with the rest of your project and easily identify what is amiss.

```
const chai = require("chai")
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const nock = require("nock")
const http = require("http")

const API_ENDPOINT = 'http://postman-echo.com'

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  const outReq = http.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/get?foo=${request.url}`, () => {
    response.end()
  });

  outReq.on("error", err => {
    response.statusCode = 400;
    response.write(JSON.stringify({error: err.message}))
    response.end()
  })
});

describe("endpoint testing", () => {
  afterEach((done) => {
    nock.cleanAll();
    done();
  });

  it("should return 200", (done) => {
    chai
      .request(server)
      .get(`/endpoint/live`)
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .send()
      .then((res) => {
        chai.expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
        done();
      })
      .catch(done);
  });

  it("should return 400 if a connection error occur with API", (done) => {
    const apiNock = nock(API_ENDPOINT)
      .get('/get?foo=/endpoint/fake')
      .replyWithError({
        message: "Something awful happened",
        code: "404",
      });

    chai
      .request(server)
      .get(`/endpoint/fake`)
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .send()
      .then((res) => {
        chai.expect(apiNock.isDone()).to.be.true;
        chai.expect(res.status).to.equal(400);
        chai.expect(res.text).to.equal('{"error":"Something awful happened"}');
        done();
      })
      .catch(done);
  });
});
```

Comment: In the code that you provided, you created a new server that simulate the API using http and all the requests from API_ENDPOINT will pass though there? I dont get why do we need that new server creation. I just want to make real request to the API and have it intercept in some unit test

Comment: that was just to make a stand alone example that worked. you shouldn't need it.